# Would you use the word "swum" these days?

Tags: grammaticality, irregular, ablaut, non-standard, strong-verbs

Would you use the word "swum" these days? I mean, grammatically, it is the past participle of the verb "to swim", but it seems to me that no one uses it anymore. If it's the case, how would You describe the fact that You have already performed an act of swimming today? With "swum" it would be like this: "I've already swum today"

Comment: People do use "swum"; just not everybody.  (I use it, for example, in normal everyday speech).

Comment: I have swum today.
I swam today.
I have been swimming today.

Comment: I've only heard Americans use 'I've swam' in their speech. Everyone else I've heard uses 'I've swum'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would see that word for swim race or competition:

> I have already swum (the 500m swim race) today

as opposed to the more common

> I have already been swimming today

or:

> I have already gone swimming today

(you generally "go swimming", not just "swim")

Comment: ...as opposed to the simple past, e.g.: "last week, I *swam* in a race".

Comment: Also "I've swum twenty lengths today" is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 6):

A quick, unscientific survey of Google and Google NGram suggests:

- *swum* is still widely considered as being the correct past participle of *swim*.
- *I've swam* is more common than *I've swum* in casual usage.
- In formal usage and printed material, *I've swum* is still much more common.

Are there any trained linguistics willing to weigh in on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

The difference, not directly pointed out thus far, is that swam stands on its own. Swum needs a helping verb such as have. It is a difference in the KIND of past tense. Popularity is not, in the short run, a measure of correctness. Over time, language, being a fluid thing may change its rules

Comment: "Swum" is standardly called a past *participle,* not a different kind of past tense.